# How to use the variable in gnome-terminal command

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am trying to just echo a variable in gnome-terminal command

```
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "echo $1"'
```

I followed the below link for the command

[Link to the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373186/open-gnome-terminal-window-and-execute-2-commands?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I am not getting anything on the terminal, how to use the variables here?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Inside single quotes everything is preserved literally, without exception.

That means you have to close the quotes, insert something, and then re-enter again like this.

```
cmd -arg 'cmd before'${variable}'cmd after'
```

So in your case it will be:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "echo '${1}'"'
```